# Add logo to the backend top navbar

Tags: css, xml, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I'm trying to add my logo to the top navbar like this:

[image]

I modified the xml file `addons\web\static\src\xml\menu.xml` and added this div:

```html
<div style="height: 100%;display: block;float: left;margin-right: 15px;margin-left: 15px;">
   <img src="https://www.clubsportive.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-example.jpg" height=100%/>
</div>
```

inside the header like this:

```html
<header t-name="Menu" style="background-color: #4c4c4c;">
    <nav class="o_main_navbar">
        <ul class="o_menu_apps"/>
        <div style="height: 100%;display: block;float: left;margin-right: 15px;margin-left: 15px;">
            <img src="https://www.clubsportive.nl/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/logo-example.jpg" height=100%/>
        </div>
        <a class="o_menu_brand" role="button"/>
        <ul class="o_menu_sections" role="menu"/>
        <ul class="o_menu_systray" role="menu"/>
    </nav>
</header>
```

But it breaks everything. I see only white page after the change.
And there are errors inside the console:

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: The QWeb templates of Odoo are extended a lot by modules or apps. Maybe you broke the whole extension chain by changing the original file. Try to use an extension instead of modifying Odoo's original codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work fine, change ***height=100*** to ***height="100"*** [Use double quotes]

[image]

The error you get is xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 8, column 102 -, you can check it from log file.

**Note**: its always recommended to inherit than editing original code.

Comment: I'm slowly learning about custom modules and I would like to add this logo with it. But what module should I inherit and what path should I put inside xpath to targed propper element?